# svg path rendering speed

Tags: svg, d3.js, html-rendering

There are about 6000 svg path elements. Each is like:

```
<path fill="none" d="M -1180.753662,3450.687500 C -1183.848267,3258.348389              
-899.981628, 2965.197998 -707.642639,2962.103516" stroke="#8f87a8"/>
```

I am using d3 translate and scale events to pan and zoom the whole svg. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999 
It seems that html page has to re-render all of them with each pan or zoom, and that make the action quite sluggish.

Is there anyway that I can make pan and zoom smoother in theory?

Comment: Have you tried using an SVG clip path to only show what you need?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm not sure I know what do you mean. I know clip path basic but not a expert. How can I don't render elements that go out of svg canvas?

Comment: Following up from your comment on my question, I'd still like to see a  fiddle of this. Try adding 100 paths at a time and see when the zooming gets unbearably laggy, and test this threshold is the same on all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS3 transformations.

Mike Bostock has an [example of a zoomable map](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) and uses CSS3 translation and scaling to achieve smooth zooming. This approach has drawbacks: if your zoomed container has text, it will get "zoomed in" as well. But this might not matter to you or you can work around it.

Comment: I'm already using transformation. Now I think the rendering part is the bottleneck, although I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: I don't know your SVG, but maybe there is a way to group them at a lower zoom level? Do your users really need to have the possibility to interact with each of the 6000 elements?